# How to format html tables to not need a scroll bar in rendered rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra, gt

I have tables that I’ve saved with `gtsave` and `save_kable`. How do you format the sizes of html tables you’ve saved and called? I want to not have to use the scroll bar when looking at the tables in my knitted markdown (html output).

The tables right now, after rendering the rmarkdown, are small and you have to use scroll bar to scroll downwards and to the side, you can’t see the whole table on the page.

I’d very much appreciate any help in making the tables look readable.

My rmarkdown looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(knitr)
Library(kableExtra)

table_gt_tbl %>% gtsave(“table_gt_tbl”, path = “PATH”)
```

`![](PATH/table_gt_tbl.html “dog breeds”)`

```
music %>% select(ID, location, address, music_type) %>% knitr::kable() %>% kable_styling(latex_options = c(“scale_down”, “HOLD_position”) %>% kableExtra::save_kable(“PATH/music.html”)
```

`![](PATH/music.html “music locations”)`

Comment: What type of output are you using? `html_document`? `flex_dashboard`?

Comment: `html_document`

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollbars are probably automatically added because the output `html_document` adds what I think are *obnoxious* margins.

I would suggest that you start by adding the following CSS. This can go anywhere in your RMD, just make sure it's not in a chunk.

```
<style>
.main-container {
  max-width: unset;
}
</style>
```

If that isn't enough, try adding height and width.

```
![](PATH/table_gt_tbl.html “dog breeds”){width=100% height=100%}
```

If you call the tables with R, you won't need to set the height and width. If you use the tables as you did in your example, as a saved .HTML file, you will probably need both.

Here's what I used to test this

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: '2022-05-17'
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)
data(gtcars)
```

<style>
.main-container {
  max-width: unset;
}
</style>

# wuz up?

```{r gts}

gtcars %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "model") %>%
  tab_stubhead(label = "car")

```

## TELL ME MORE!!! 

```{r yaaaTablezzz}

gtcars %>%
  slice(1:5) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "model") %>%
  tab_stubhead(label = "car") %>% 
  gtsave("table_gt_tbl.html", path = "../_html")

```

![](../_html/table_gt_tbl.html){width=100% height=100%}
````